# Why does this regular expression fail?

Tags: php, regex, special-characters

I have a password validation script in PHP that checks a few different regular expressions, and throws a unique error message depending on which one fails. Here is an array of the regular expressions and the error messages that are thrown if the match fails:

```
array(
    'rule1' => array(
        '/^.*[\d].*$/i',
        'Password must contain at least one number.'
    ),
    'rule2' => array(
        '/^.*[a-z].*$/i',
        'Password must contain at least one lowercase letter'
    ),
    'rule3' => array(
        '/^.*[A-Z].*$/i',
        'Password must contain at least one uppercase letter'
    ),
    'rule4' => array(
        '/^.*[~!@#$%^&*()_+=].*$/i',
        'Password must contain at least one special character [~!@#$%^&*()_+=]'
    )
);
```

For some reason, no matter what I pass through the validation, the "Special Characters" rule fails.  I'm guessing it's a problem with the expression.  If there's a better (or correct) way to write these expressions, I'm all ears!

Comment: the rule looks ok, maybe it's how you're using it, please provide more code

Comment: Note: using `^` and `$` anchors and adding `.*` around your pattern is useless. Also don't use a character class if you specify only one entity. `/^.*[\d].*$/` is equivalent to `/\d/` (same applies to other rules).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't see a problem with your special characters regular expression, but I can see a problem with the upper and lower case checks:

```
/^.*[A-Z].*$/i
```

The `i` at the end means [PCRE_CASELESS](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), i.e. it will ignore case. You should omit the `i`.

Comment: Way to roll a nice spot check!

Comment: Grr.. Beat me to it. In fact, he should remove them from all four of his regex as they are either circumventing their intended purpose or they are completely irrelevant to the search (special chars/numbers).

Comment: @webbiedave. Yep, also the `[...]` around `\d` are unnecessary. :)

Comment: And he should remove both the `.*`,  `^` and `$` as they are just emulating the functionality of `/[A-Z]/`

Comment: Marked this answer as correct since it, plus the comments, contains the most help.  I've implemented all of the suggestions to clean up the redundancies.  Turns out the problem was worthy of a big FACEPALM.  I was hashing the password prior to testing for validation.  Thanks for the help, anyway!

Comment: Team effort. Glad we could help.

Answer (score 1):

The regex should simply be:

```
/[~!@#$%^&*()_+=]/
```

No need for the stars. Either way your regex should work.

I would **check the function that's using the array** to see if there are any logic errors.

Also, as Mark Byers stated, you should remove the insensitive modifiers `/i`

Comment: To develop, all the /^.* .*$/ you do can be replaced by / /

Answer (score 0):

This works ([as seen on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/slJ14jrC2R)):

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[~!@#$%^&*()_+=]).*
```

This uses lookahead (which is supported by PHP's `preg` functions, since they're PCRE) instead of matching all the different rules. I'm not sure why yours doesn't work.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [Flavor comparison](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) ([PHP](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html))